# exclude many users in mysql

Tags: mysql, long-integer

thank you very much in advance for the help.
I have to make an exclusion of users, the problem is that it takes too long to do (about 5 hours or more)
In my database I have about 800,000 users of which I exclude around 580000 users (I get the 220000 users that are not repeated).

1. to make this a first method:

`SELECT iduser FROM userstotal WHERE iduser NOT IN( SELECT iduser FROM users220000)`

(This is a simplified example of what I do but that's the idea)
This takes about 5 hours or more to perform the query.

I was thinking of a php script to add in an array of users and then go excluding repeated.

That you advise me to optimize the SQL query or some optimum method for this.

- For reference use MyISAM

Comment: Can you show us the query plan? (run the query with `EXPLAIN ` in front of the `SELECT`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rewrite the query as

```
SELECT   ut.iduser
FROM     userstotal ut
WHERE    NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT  u2.iduser 
           FROM    users220000 u2 
           WHERE   u2.iduser = ut.iduser
         )
```

and make sure that `iduser` of the `userstotal` table is [indexed](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html).

*I doubt an index on users220000 would make any difference but it wouldn't hurt either.*

### edit

Thanks to Ronnis for spotting the missing clause.

Comment: Many thank you very much to everyone who actually helped me the query takes 10 minutes, it's great.

Thanks again

Comment: Don't run that query in production. Add the missing join condition first :)

Comment: @Ronnis - as in 'The Matrix': *there is no missing join*

Comment: The query as written will return 0 rows as long as there is at least 1 row in table users220000. There IS a missing join :)

Comment: @Ronnis - you were right all allong. Thanks for spotting the error.